# Using the Feed Dialog from the JS SDK with a link to an image

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

To start, I know that this question has been asked a number of times over the past years but as Facebook's features evolve very regularly, what could be done 1 or 2 years ago usually cannot now...

What I am trying to achieve is to post an image to the user's albums, and then post a feed to his wall with a link/attachment to the posted image. All with the JS SDK.
I can do the first step using `FB.api('/me/photos',...)`.
For the second step, I'm using a Dialog by calling `FB.ui({method: 'feed',...})` which works well except that I haven't found any (currently working) parameter that can link the image I've posted at the first step.

Thanks in advance!